# How best to display a picture comparison in IOS?

Tags: gui-design, ios, image, voting, comparison

SO I want to allow my user to compare two pictures and decide between one or the other through a thumbs up/down.  I also have a list of these, so there are multiple 'cards' with this comparison and my user should be able to scroll through them.

What is the most effective way of showing this on an iphone? I could display the images side by side - but I thought that makes things a little crowded?

Answer (score 2):

It being crowded depends on the amount of interface elements you want to show. You could keep things real intuitive and make use of the limited space you have on the screen by just showing the two images and using swipe gestures for navigation.

[image: concept]

In this quick mockup I've used the landscape orientation because I think for comparison a side by side comparison is more effective than a top down comparison. On the second screen I've added the cover flow we all remember from the iPod Touch. This could be a great intuitive way of browsing through your deck of 'cards' and you won't have to add buttons or other elements possibly cluttering the interface.

I hope this idea is of some inspiration for you.